# Is Office Web Apps 2010 compatible with SharePoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint farm consisting of:

Server 1: SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 64-bit.

Server 2: Microsoft Office 2010 32-bit (and other third party tools and services) on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit.

Since Office Web Apps 2013 is only available in 64-bit, can I install Office Web Apps 2010 32-bit on Server 2 and integrate it with SharePoint 2013? Is it Compatible?

If not, then will installing Office Web Apps 2013 64-bit work if installed on a third server (Server 3) even though Office 2010 32-bit is being used in the farm.

Installing Office 2013 64-bit on Server 2 is not an option.

Thanks, Mario.

Answer (score 0):

OWA in SharePoint 2010 is part of service application while in SharePoint 2013 it is separate dedicated application i.e WFmgr. So you can not install it on 2013 server.

SO it is not possible to use OWA 2010 to SP2013.